# Why do I get bloated stomach when in office but not at home?

Tags: nutrition, diet, digestion, stomach, bloated-bloating

I work in a software company. When in office, I tend to eat moderately. I make sure I have a short stroll every hour in office. At the end of the day, I end up getting bloated stomach. But when I'm home and not being much physically active, even if I eat more than I eat in office, I don't get bloated stomach. What could be the reason?

Comment: We can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Eating less or more doesn't necessarily reduce or add to bloating. It could be the types of food that you are eating.

Dairy, grains, and legumes are common culprits. See link below for a good explanation.

Source:
http://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-foods-that-cause-bloating

Comment: Note that consumption of beans/legumes etc when they are new or infrequent to your diet can cause bloating, but that usually resolves after a few weeks with frequent consumption.